# Django model.save() Not Effecting New Instances of Same Model

Tags: python, django

I've hit this bug in an application I'm working on and have replicated it in a new django server instance to test. Here is the shell I ran:

```
user@hostname:~/testproject$ sudo python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from testapp.models import testmodel

In [2]: a = testmodel.objects.first()

In [3]: print(a.testvar1)
0

In [4]: a.testvar1 = 1

In [5]: print(a.testvar1)
1

In [6]: a.save()

In [7]: b = testmodel.objects.first()

In [8]: print(b.testvar1)
0
```

So could someone please explain why I can't adjust values of model instances and have those changes take effect when model.save() is run? I can't find any alternate way of modifying models in the Django documentation but any direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `testvar` a model.Field instance? Only model fields will be saved to the database. Other attributes are not persisted. Please add the class definition for `testmodel` to your question.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks Haken Lid

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any problems.
You can only keep one data in your database and do what you have done again.
I suspect that the results of your first search are inconsistent with the results of the second search.